# iOS Game Size problem

Tags: ios, memory, size

I developed an iOS Universal game and I want to know if 100mb means that the game is very large compared to other games, I really have a problem with those .png images which are over 8mb each

Comment: Use [pngquant](http://pngquant.org) for those PNGs. At least they'll be 2MB each :) Or if you don't need transparency, then just use JPEG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

100mb is a very large app, but it isn't unusual for a highly immersion or graphical game.  Since you are over 20mb your app will only be available to be downloaded over a WiFi connection or through iTunes so you will want to make sure the extra 80mb makes your game compelling enough to get users to purchase it using these methods.  But to be more specific, I have seen several games that are this large or larger (Myst is 534mb and GTA Chinatown is 232mb - but both already have big followings to help convince users to get these).

I do find it strange that you would have .png images that are that large, however.  Even if you can't get it under 20mb, reducing your file size/resources will almost certainly create a better user experience (at least in performance if nothing else).

Comment: Agreed; I'd try converting the PNGs to JPEGs for starters...